# Permutations of a specific set of numbers from n to m

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n, m, x[20], p[20];
void display(){

for(int i = 1 ; i <= n; ++i)
    cout << x[i] << ' ';
cout << "\n";

}
void bkt(int k){

for(int i = n; i <= m; ++i)
if(!p[i]){

    x[k] = i;
    p[i] = 1;
    if(k<n)
        bkt(k+1);
        else
        display();
    p[i] = 0;
  }

}

int main()
{ cin >> n >> m;
bkt(1);



    return 0;
}
```

This code should do the permutations from n to m, but it doesn't work and I don't know what I did wrong. I tried a set of examples like 4 and 6, and it should show

```
4 5 6 
4 6 5 
5 4 6 
5 6 4 
6 4 5 
6 5 4
```

but it doesn't show anything in the console, just returns 0.

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of issues with the code, but you can solve the problem in the following way:

```
cin >> n >> m;  // get range
```

Then create a vector of the appropriate size

```
std::vector<int> v(m - n + 1);
```

and then fill it with the needed values

```
std::iota(std::begin(v), std::end(v), n);
```

and then generate all permutations in a loop

```
do {
  // ...
} while(std::next_permuation(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
```